# CSVHelper - how to write Multiple Header Rows

Tags: header

I am working with Amazon Uploader Template Files that have three header rows, where the second and third are column specific and the first row is also lined up to some degree.

I need to be able to write these three headers out properly when I write the data to a CSV file and I cannot find any means by which to control this.

I have an Object and Map configured for the third row, but I have no idea how to create the first two rows.  The second and third row columns must match, the first row must always be as the original was presented.

In other words, as long as the column headers from the second and third row are together the column order of these two rows can change, but the first row must always be the same.

I cannot find anything in CSVHelper that will manage this the way I need to.  Is there a means by which I can manage these two header rows via CSVHelper?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a row, including a header row, any way you like using the `WriteField` method.

```cs
csv.WriteField("First");
csv.WriteField("Row");
csv.WriteField("Headers");
csv.NextRecord();
```

If you have a class that you want the headers written for, you can use the `WriteHeader` method.

```cs
csv.WriteHeader<RowClass>();
csv.NextRecord();
```

You will need to specify the order of the fields written by either putting an `[Index(int index)]` attribute on the property or by creating a map and mapping the property to an index.

Write your 3 headers using one of the above methods, and then you can write the rows as you normally would.

```cs
csv.WriteRecords(records);
```

Comment: Hi Josh, the first row is a fixed format and I can see how you presented a solution I can implement.  The second row has to correlate with the columns, you suggest using the Index for that, I will take a look at that and see if I can figure out what you mean in terms of the code I would need.  Thanks for the response, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: I have most of this figured out but one of my goals is to make it more mantainable.  Is there any way to provide the text that would be in the second row above the header that is generated directly from the property names?  This would be a really nice way to deal with this, we could put something like [Header{"headertext")] before each property and the writer would then understand to put these lines in the rows before.

This would allow each property to have as many rows as needed directly associated with the property and that would be super easy to maintain.